# Uploaded file from 'file' type input field is not showing in img field

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, image

I am not being able to change displayed image on file upload using javascript.This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> File Upload </title>
    <script>
        function uploadFile() {
            document.getElementById('picturefield').src='file:///'+document.frmaddstudent.picturefile.src;
            //document.getElementById('picturefield').src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-2/128/man-icon.png';
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <b>Image</b>
    <form name="frmaddstudent">
        <img id="picturefield" src="file:///C:/Users/Nasim/Desktop/myimage.jpg">
        <input type="file" name="picturefile" onchange="uploadFile()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But the image is not being changed on file upload from my pc. The value of
`document.frmaddstudent.picturefile.src`
shows **empty string** as I debugged with firebug.

If I use
`document.frmaddstudent.picturefile.value`
instead of
`document.frmaddstudent.picturefile.src`,
then the value shows only the selected file name, but I **need the full file path** to set as the **`img`** `src`.

Can anyone please tell me what is the wrong thing I am doing here? Is there any easy solution in Javascript/jQuery to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern browsers doesn't support this feature of `input file` for security reasons.

You would have to upload that file and then show it in `img`

Comment: no no no there is something called file reader in Mozilla which is supported in many Brow. other than IE

Comment: Ok than that would be interesting to know plz post that here as a solution.

Comment: That one requires script/Activex run confirmation on IE, But still a good one, I didn't knew that +1.

Comment: Didn't check @AnkitGautam 's link, because I need it to work on IE too. Seems like I have to avoid doing it like this and do the other way (may be as yogi suggested)

Comment: @HeartBeat there is a solution for IE too

Comment: see the code https://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/6232/=crossbrowser_image_preview.html

Comment: Yeah @AnkitGautam that was the link which I had visited :).

Comment: I've seen that code, but I need my code to support as back as IE-8, and that code is not working in IE8.